# JavaScript inside C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<script>
 ...

   var Klasa = calEvent.ClassID;
   @{
     var NameOfClass = Model.FirstOrDefault(xx => xx.ClassID == @:Klasa).Nazwa_Klasy;
   }

  $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Klasa:</b>' + @NameOfClass

 ...
</script>
```

How should I correct mix JS with C#?

I get information 'Cannot use local variable "NameOfClass" before it is declared',

but when I declare variable again before with string value then I get 'An opening "(" is missing the corresponding closing ")"' and then I am not sure what exactly I should do, because everything looks all right.

My main target is that I want to get single data from Model (Nazwa_Klasy) where ClassID is equal calEvent.ClassID. Maybe should I also change my expression?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: `@:Klasa` doesn't look valid.  Not valid syntax.

Comment: You can't pass the (JavaScript) value of `Klasa` to Razor like that. The Razor would have already executed on the server.

Comment: The problem is `calEvent.ClassId`, being javascript won't have a value on server side.  Any C# in Razor such as `@{...}` is going to run server side.  It won't be able to reference `calEvent.ClassID` because that is javascript which doesn't have a value until the page is rendered in the browser. You'll probably need to show more of your code and some context for us to help you formulate a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's clarify few things:

This will be `var Klasa = calEvent.ClassID;` happening on the client side. Means, some action will cause `calEvent` in the browser.
If *yes*, then it makes following pointless.

```
Model.FirstOrDefault(xx => xx.ClassID == @:Klasa)
```

As on the server (where this is run), `klasa` is not available. So your best bet is to spit `Model`, which seems to be an array on the client side and then filter that. Don't know if I'm making any sense, but do give following a try:

```
<script>
    ...
    //Array of object to look into at client side
    var modelArray=@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
    var Klasa = calEvent.ClassID;

    var NameOfClass=null;
    $.each(modelArray,function(){
        if($(this).ClassID===klasa){
            NameOfClass = $(this).Nazwa_Klasy;
            return;
        }
    });

    //You may want to test if `NameOfClass` has a value.
    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Klasa:</b>' + NameOfClass
 ...
</script>
```

Also, as pointed out in comments, `@:klasa` is wrong. You don't need `:` there.

Answer (score 0):

@TheVillageIdiot the way of Your thinking was good, but the code didn't work properly as I wanted. So, I changed it a little to

```
     var modelArray = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
                var Klasa = calEvent.ClassID;


                for (var i = 0; i < modelArray.length; i++) {
                    var obj = modelArray[i];
                    if (obj.ClassID === Klasa) {
                        NameOfClass = obj.Nazwa_Klasy.trim();
                    }
                }


                $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Klasa: </b>' + NameOfClass));
```

Right now everything is fine.

Thanks a lot! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the *quick* answer to your question, but there's a live demo addressing the issue of working with JavaScript inside ASP.NET MVC apps this week. It's on Oct 26 and I'm sure there will be a recording afterwards if you can't attend. [This is the registration page.](https://www.telerik.com/campaigns/aspnet-mvc/dotnet-devchat-structure-javascript-code-within-aspnet-mvc-app/) - you can also ask your questions there.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should tell this as a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. But I can't leave comments (to other people's posts) as I'm a novice user.

Comment: Till then try to build the reputation by helping people with answers and other things then post a comment. But don't do like this.